# Python from crosstab to dictionary to table

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary named kyc

```
kyc = {u'0G-0009': {u'JIMMY UNDERSON': {u'Z609 GURU': {'d8': 46, 'd6': 57, 'd7': None, 'd4': 41, 'd5': 251, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}, u'0G-0008': {u'ASSOU EKOTO': {u'13-2003 GURU RED': {'d8': None, 'd6': None, 'd7': None, 'd4': None, 'd5': None, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}, u'0G-0007': {u'WILFRED BONY': {u'17-2849 RUT RED': {'d8': None, 'd6': None, 'd7': None, 'd4': 26, 'd5': 35, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}, u'0G-0006': {u'PETER MICHELLE': {u'Z007 GURU': {'d8': 230, 'd6': None, 'd7': None, 'd4': None, 'd5': None, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}, u'0G-0005': {u'DICKSON GONA': {u'13-2002 RUT RED': {'d8': None, 'd6': None, 'd7': None, 'd4': 70, 'd5': 77, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}, u'0G-0004': {u'KASAGO PEACE': {u'Z2053 GURU': {'d8': None, 'd6': None, 'd7': None, 'd4': None, 'd5': None, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}, u'0G-0003': {u'CEDRIC ABDU': {u'Z0191 GURU': {'d8': None, 'd6': None, 'd7': None, 'd4': None, 'd5': None, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}, u'0G-0002': {u'CEASER SAMPIO': {u'Z1146 GURU': {'d8': None, 'd6': None, 'd7': None, 'd4': None, 'd5': None, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}, u'0G-0001': {u'JOHN SPEKE': {u'Z 006 GURU': {'d8': 21, 'd6': 34, 'd7': None, 'd4': None, 'd5': None, 'd2': None, 'd3': None, 'd1': None}}}}
```

the keys d8 to d1 reprent dates ie from 1st to 8th - with sales values attached to them

I would like to print data from this dictionary in the structure below:

```
0G-0009 |JIMMY UNDERSON |Z609 GURU |46

0G-0009 |JIMMY UNDERSON |Z609 GURU |57

0G-0009 |JIMMY UNDERSON |Z609 GURU |None

0G-0009 |JIMMY UNDERSON |Z609 GURU |41

0G-0009 |JIMMY UNDERSON |Z609 GURU |251

0G-0009 |JIMMY UNDERSON |Z609 GURU |None

0G-0009 |JIMMY UNDERSON |Z609 GURU |None

0G-0008 |ASSOU EKOTO |13-2003 GURU RED |None

0G-0008 |ASSOU EKOTO |13-2003 GURU RED |None

0G-0008 |ASSOU EKOTO |13-2003 GURU RED |None

0G-0008 |ASSOU EKOTO |13-2003 GURU RED |None

0G-0008 |ASSOU EKOTO |13-2003 GURU RED |None

0G-0008 |ASSOU EKOTO |13-2003 GURU RED |None

0G-0008 |ASSOU EKOTO |13-2003 GURU RED |None
```

-- etc

my current code is

```
for i in range(1,9):
    for k1 in kyc:
        #print k1,
        for k2 in kyc[k1]:
            #print k2,
            for k3 in kyc[k1][k2]:
                #print k3,
                for k4 in kyc[k1][k2][k3]:
                    print k1,
                    print k2,
                    print k3,
                    print kyc[k1][k2][k3]['d'+str(i)]
```

But it returns each row 8 times (from the range), how should i deal with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently iterating over all the keys in the dictionary 8 times, because your first and last for loop do the same thing.  Either your first or your last for loop is unnecessary.  I got rid of the first one and got what I believe to be the correct result with this:

```
for k1 in kyc:
    for k2 in kyc[k1]:
        for k3 in kyc[k1][k2]:
            for k4 in kyc[k1][k2][k3]:
                print k1,
                print k2,
                print k3,
                print kyc[k1][k2][k3][k4]
```